# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 40483812 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 5MB until OOM

Tags: android, gridview

I Have a Gridview with lot of Images from my Drawable folder,When i open the Gridview and if i tried to scroll,app is crashing by showing error above.Help me by solving this problem,I have also Added `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` and `android:largeHeap="true"` but it doesn't worked for me.Thanks In Advance,Help me to solve this.

**Here is my Code for Adapter Class**

```
public class IndianCricketTeamAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
private Context mContext;
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {R.drawable.india_team1, 
R.drawable.india_team2,
        R.drawable.india_team3, R.drawable.india_team4,
        R.drawable.india_team5, R.drawable.indian_team6,
        R.drawable.indain_team7, R.drawable.india_team8, R.drawable.india_team9, R.drawable.india_team10, R.drawable.india_team11,
        R.drawable.india_team12, R.drawable.india_team13, R.drawable.india_team14};

public IndianCricketTeamAdapter(Context c)
{
    mContext=c;
}
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(500,450));
    imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    return imageView;

}
}
```

**And MainActivity code is Here**

```
 public class IndianTeamFullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
 {
 Button setWallpaper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_indian_team_full_screen);
    setWallpaper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Set_Wallpaper);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    final int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    final IndianCricketTeamAdapter imageAdapter = new IndianCricketTeamAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

    setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setWallpaper.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorstatelist));
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]));
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

            int height = dm.heightPixels;
            int width = dm.widthPixels;

            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bm);
                wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(height, width);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(IndianTeamFullScreenActivity.this, "Set Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: your images are simply too large to be handled by android device, the only way to fix it is to reduce image size (or load them pre-scaled)

Comment: There are many libraries that help you loading images such as Picasso or Glide : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Must-Have-Libraries#overview